# css3 gradient custom background

Tags: css, gradient

Is it possible to create body background like this
http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/03/15/1cc/e97/6b8ad17874dc9542a6fbfb833a46fd114579f6f8.jpg
with just css3 properties?

Comment: Multi gradients are possible to create but they still have compatibility in legacy browsers. check this [link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it "_**Needs debugging details**: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem._"; NOTE: This is currently a link only question and the **"link is broken"**.